# Android getting package name of application from received share intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

In my android application, I have registered for intent filter android.intent.action.SEND in one of my activities to receive data from other applications.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
```

When data is shared from other apps with my app using share intent, this activity receives the intent. I would like to know the package name of app which shared the data with my app.

I tried following code but it always returns null.

```
final String packageName = this.getCallingPackage()
```

Is there any way I can get the package name of app that shared data with my app using intent that i am receiving?

Comment: You can check and see what `Binder.getCallingUID()` returns. My guess, though, is it will be the system if a chooser was involved.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Yeah its returning same uid every time with different apps. So most probably would be of system.

Comment: Then, off the cuff, I don't think there's a way for you to get that info.

Comment: I'll try to get info from either url that is shared or the name of folder in which file is stored in case of images etc

Comment: try to check here : http://www.geeks.gallery/sharing-application-data-between-two-apps-part-iii/

Answer (score 2):

If the share intent was created using [ShareCompat.IntentBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.html) it will contain the extra [EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.html#EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE).
But most apps don't provide this information. And if the extra is present you should not use it for any security-critical functionality because senders are free to provide any value they like.

Answer (score 0):

To use **getCallingPackage()**, the caller should use **startActivityForResult(Intent, int)** instead of **startActivity()**. Otherwise, it will return null. Straight from the doc:

> Note: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it
>   did not use the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) form that includes
>   a request code), then the calling package will be null.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingPackage%28%29